# How To remove the negative signs from total_amount, qty, and rate column in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
transaction_id  cust_id tran_date   prod_subcat_code    prod_cat_code   Qty Rate    Tax total_amt   Store_type
0   80712190438 270351  28-02-2014  1                          1          -5    -772    405.300 -4265.300   e-Shop
1   29258453508 270384  27-02-2014  5                          3          -5    -1497   785.925 -8270.925   e-Shop
2   51750724947 273420  24-02-2014  6                          5          -2    -791    166.110 -1748.110   TeleShop
3   93274880719 271509  24-02-2014  11                         6           -3   -1363   429.345 -4518.345   e-Shop
4   51750724947 273420  23-02-2014  6                          5           -2   -791    166.110 -1748.110   TeleShop
```

How To remove the negative signs from each column?

Comment: Please describe what you have tried and pleas be clear

Comment: Oh so you want to make the numbers positive right?

Comment: yes,from the dataset it is given in -ve sign in some of the numeric value.i want to remove that sign so i can visualize it correctly.                                                                 i have tried this                                                                                                                     amounts = [] #array declaration
for j in df2['total_amt']:
     amounts.append(j.replace('-','').strip())

data['total_amt']= amounts
data['total_amt']= data['total_amt'].astype('int')

Answer (score 3):

```py
df[['Qty', 'Rate', 'Tax', 'total_amt']].apply(abs)
```

Here I'm using the built-in `abs`(absolute value of the number) to convert the negative numbers into positive ones.

Comment: Can u look at  the dataset once....because its not properly working

Comment: How to put all these in one line like all the numeric and non numeric column so when i see it df.head() it will show all in +ve with other columns.

Comment: So basically you only want to see the numeric columns when you call ```df.head```?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225856/discussion-between-biswajit-kumar-singh-and-aryan-mishra).